# How to filter a range in Google Sheets Apps Script to search value in this range but only in odd rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that is searching a value in a range (with createTextFinder), just to set the current cell :

`sh1.setCurrentCell(sh1.getRange(3, 1, sh1.getLastRow()-2, sh1.getLastColumn()).createTextFinder(folio).matchEntireCell(true).findNext());`

But I'd rather search my "folio" value only in odd rows : that would prevent errors I can have when searching also in even rows (there I have different kind of values, and searching there is not really relevant anyway).

So I'm looking for a way to filter out even rows from the search range. That sounds quite basic but I can't find much when I google it… So any help would be great ! Thx in advance !

Answer (score 2):

You can use this modification to skip the results until a cell from an odd row is found:

```
  var textFinder = sh1.getRange(3, 1, sh1.getLastRow() - 2, sh1.getLastColumn()).createTextFinder(folio).matchEntireCell(true);
  while(cell = textFinder.findNext()){
    if (cell.getRow() % 2 !== 0){
      break;
    }
  }
  if(cell !== null) sh1.setCurrentCell(cell);
```

This uses the [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) object to continue searching using `findNext()`.